# Basic python lists accessing

Tags: python, list, loops

These are three lists of python.

```
List1 = [a,b,c]
List2 = [1,2,3]
List3 = [X,Y,Z]
```

Is it possible to get Output like this ?

Output :

a

1

X

(After delay of 10 sec)

b

2

Y

(After delay of 10 sec)

c

3

Z

I tried it with nested for loops but unable to get desired output. Is there any good approach?

Comment: Use `zip()` and `time.sleep()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
from time import sleep

List1 = ['a','b','c']
List2 = [1,2,3]
List3 = ['X','Y','Z']

for i, j, k in zip(List1, List2, List3):
    print(f'Output:\n{i}\n{j}\n{k}')
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: Might be useful to point out that zip on a 2D matrix (sub arrays of equal length) acts as a transpose to the matrix. i.e. `tuple(zip((1, 2), (3, 4))) == ((1, 3), (2, 4))`

Comment: Can you please tell me how to  get the output of list1 like ''+a", "+b", etc:

+a

1

X

and so on

Comment: Simply put a "+" in the string like so: `print(f'Output:\n+{i}\n{j}\n{k}')`